# Connect to microsoft sql server from spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using microsoft sql server,

If i open intellij, open new database connection in database tool window =>

[image]

and in advanced type i add:
[image]

The connection works. However now i want to connect to this ms sql server with spring jpa. So what i am using is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;instance=<instance>;domain=<domain>;useNTLMv2=true
spring.datasource.username=<user>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

And it just says "login for user failed"

In my pom i am using:

```
<!-- jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.jpa.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Why does it work with database tool window, but not with jpa?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Your are mixing **JDBC** driver connecting with sprig data **JPA** connection, for JPA proper connection you can change the drive class name to

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Then the dialect can be

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

And finally add the proper url and remove JDBC driver relavent dependencies

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=<dbname>
```

Remaining properties will be same as your, see both examples in [here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-examples) .

Comment: Please see here as well .https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574118/15758781

Comment: if i dont use jtds driver, it refuses connection even in intellij database tool window. I tried to use your properties, but the error remains 'login failed for user'